# Do we really need to use polymer?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, dart, polymer

I am very interested in polymer when learning Dart, which make it possible for building repeatable complex web components in web application. My question is, is it possible to simply build these repeatable components with native JavaScript(without Dart), do we really need to integrate Polymer to our client side code?

PS. I guess for some web application like game would use some complex components very often.

Comment: Are you asking about Dart or about JavaScript? You can clone and add each DOM element as often as you like using just Dart or JavaScript. No need for Polymer.

Comment: You can write your own Polymer or even Dart. But why would you?  Polymer for Web Components is like jQuery for JS.

Comment: Might be you have some specific complains about Polymer? But again it's modular and Dart has tree shaking  so it's not like you will have too much overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polymer has been create in the spirit to make the web easier to understand (and to develop), so the aims of the polymer project it's that your web browser directly offer you some beautiful and reusable web component.

But today, it's not the case so the developper of the Polymer project created a JS library to emulate the principle. [enter link description here](http://www.polymer-project.org) Here the link of the project.

The integration of polymer in dart is pretty visible because it's 2 google project that has been released in the same periode of time.

I invite you to see this video [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mN7IAaRdi_k) that is very interesting about the polymer project.